# List Recent Post Titles from Custom Taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization

I'm managing a movie related site.. I'm using yoast's [simple taxonomies plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/simple-taxonomies/) to classify my content with Artists, Genre (action, horror, comedy, drama etc..), Director, Writer etc...

On a specific page (template), I want to pull last 5 posts with only their titles from custom taxonomies.. how can I pull last 5 titles from Action, Comedy or Horror taxonomies as list?

I will try to get an output like http://tutsplus.com/

Thanks

Comment: genre is the taxonomy and Action, Comedy or Horror are terms in that taxonomy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create additional loops in your template, selecting the taxonomy and term you'd like to limit display to for each. for instance, this will pull the last 5 posts from taxonomy "genre", term "action":

```
<?php

$args = array( 'taxonomy'=>'genre','term'=>'action','posts_per_page'=>5 );
$action_films = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $action_films->have_posts() ) : $action_films->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: Im still kind of new to the whole php stuff but why not use a for each statement?

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx - I guess you could use a `foreach`, though you'd have to do `foreach $results->posts as $item` since the results are an object containing an array of posts, not just a flat array. you'd still have to call `$results->the_post()` to set up the data properly for all the template functions. I sometimes use a `foreach` if I'm accessing data directly from the object, but otherwise `while` is simpler, and what WordPress uses in their code and docs.

Comment: great!.. that was exactly what I wanted.. just forgot to mention permalink.. but Bainternet provided related code.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

alternative approach :

```
$genres = array('action','drama','horror','comedy');
foreach ($genres as $genre){
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'genre' => $genre ) );
    echo '<div class="genre-list"><ul>';
    while ($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></div>';
    wp_reset_query();
}
```